# 2 Application (1 is COM Visible), with shared Common Reference Library deployed on different dates

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, com, shared-libraries

I have 2 Separate Application running with same MyCommon DLL's (different versions)

In mean time MyCommonLib.dll is updated and now its version is 2.0.0
Now Create SolutionB with Project_1 which has Reference of MyCommonLib.dll (version 2.0.0) , Copied/Updated MyCommonLib.dll v2.0.0 on Project_A Executable/DLL Folder

---

In SolutionA 
    Project_A > Reference> MyCommonLib.dll (version 1.0.0) 
    Project_B>  Reference> Project_A

Point to Note : Project B is COM Visible (Windows Service) 
Build and Deployed Project_B  on date 1

Solution B 
 - Project_1 > Reference> MyCommonLib.dll (version 2.0.0) 
 - Redeployed Solution B on date 2 
 - Copy MyCommonLib.Dll (v.2 ) to SolutionA > Project_A folder

---

I have application running where on 1 event fire both application have to perform some job .. but it failed on Project_B stating for Type Project_B Could not load file or assembly MyCommonLib, Version=1.0.0 ...

With old version on both Application both runs fine , if build and deploys both both runs fine

Some one help please

Comment: DLL not registered due to DLL Hell, tried with BindingDirect already in app.config/win.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
// Constructor of > SolutionA >  ProjectB > Calling Class
public New() : base()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolve;
}


private Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs e)
{
    Assembly ass = null;
    if (e.Name.StartsWith("MyCommonLib,")) {
        string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location;
        path = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        path = IO.Path.Combine(path, "MyCommonLib.dll");
        if (IO.File.Exists(path)) {
            ass = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
        }
    }
    return ass;
}
```

Resolved